# biblatex multiple sourcemap : add field to entry

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, xetex, biber

I am trying to add a field to biblatex entries in the `tex`file. I am currently not able to apply a rule to one entry then apply it other rules to other entries.

I defined a command to add a field. Something is wrong with it but I don't know what it is:

```
\newcommand{\addnotetoentry}[2]{%
  \DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map[overwrite]{%
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey,match=\regexp{^#1$},final]%
      \step[fieldset=note,fieldvalue={#2}]%
    }%
  }%
}%
}
```

Which is used like this:

```
\addnotetoentry{a}{one note --- hello my friend}
\addnotetoentry{b}{another note}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic-verb,doi=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{a,
   author = {Doe, J.},
   title = {The Title},
   journal = {The Journal},
}
@ARTICLE{b,
   author = {Smith, J.},
   title = {The New Title},
   journal = {The Same Journal},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\addnotetoentry}[2]{%
  \DeclareSourcemap{%
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map[overwrite]{%
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey,match=\regexp{^#1$},final]%
      \step[fieldset=note,fieldvalue={#2}]%
    }%
  }%
}%
}
\addnotetoentry{a}{one note}
\addnotetoentry{b}{another note}
\AtEveryBibitem{\printfield{note}\clearfield{note}\item}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I get in the ouput's references only one note (the last one that I defined):

[image: buggy output]

Comment: I currently cannot find the reference in the documentation, but I am pretty sure one can only use one `\DeclareSourcemap` per document (only the last one will be executed), one can use an unlimited (I think) number of `\maps` in a `\DeclareSourcemap` though.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It is probably not the best idea to change bibliography data on the fly in a document. If you have to change anything, change the `.bib` file.

Comment: I don't want to modify my bib file to add notes. Since the bib file is dynamically generated remotely.

Comment: I feared you'd have a good reason to do that... I think we will have to look for a different solution. `\DeclareSourcemap` in this form does not look like your best bet...

Comment: declaring multiple `map` into one source map works (just tried), so i'm searching for a way to add maps using a command (to make it easier) , I'll look into the implementation of `DeclareSourcemap`

Comment: Exactly, this might be harder to implement in a macro though. I have found a solution that uses no sourcemapping at all, would you be interested in that?

Comment: sure :) i'd love it

Comment: You can't really use sourcemapping like this. It can only be used once in the preamble. It works by passing code to biber and so when you have the .bbl, the sourcemap is finished. You can put any number of `\map` steps in though. The `\maps` macro is used to group map steps applying to the same type of data (normally `bibtex` so you would usually have only one `\maps` macro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with Biber's `\DeclareSourcemap` is that it may only be used once in a document (only the last instance will be executed, all the other calls will be ignored)*, as such it is quite hard to implement a macro using `\DeclareSourcemap`.

If you just want to add a comment to some bibliography entries, we can go down a different route.

```
\newcommand*{\writecomment}[2]{\csdef{localcomment#1}{#2}}
```

We define `\writecomment` to define a macro `localcomment<entrykey>` (*`<entrykey>`* as given in `#1`) that takes the value `#2`.

That macro `localcomment<entrykey>` can then be used as `\csuse{localcomment<entrykey>}`, like so

Before every element:

```
\AtEveryBibitem{\csuse{localcomment\thefield{entrykey}}\item}
```

Or after every element:

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{%
  \finentry
  \ifcsdef{localcomment\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\\\csuse{localcomment\thefield{entrykey}}}
    {}%
}
```

`\csuse` will not do anything if its argument is not a valid command sequence; that means, if the macro was not created via `\writecomment` this will result in no output at all.

Another plus side of this solution is that we do not have to fiddle with the `note` field and do not override existing `note`s.

Usage of `\writecomment` is straightforward: `\writecomment{<entrykey>}{<note>}`

```
\writecomment{a}{first comment}
\writecomment{b}{second comment}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic-verb,doi=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{a,
   author = {Doe, J.},
   title = {The Title},
   journal = {The Journal},
}
@ARTICLE{b,
   author = {Smith, J.},
   title = {The New Title},
   journal = {The Same Journal},
}
@ARTICLE{c,
   author = {Miller, J.},
   title = {The New Title},
   journal = {Won't Get A Comment},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\newcommand*{\writecomment}[2]{\csdef{localcomment#1}{#2}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\csuse{localcomment\thefield{entrykey}}\item}

\writecomment{a}{first comment}
\writecomment{b}{second comment}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

* I cannot find any piece of documentation that backs this claim up, but I'm quite confident it is correct.

Comment: @pastjean I noticed you have included your use case in my answer, I have slightly modified the solution to use `\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry \ifcsdef{localcomment\thefield{entrykey}} {\\\csuse{localcomment\thefield{entrykey}}}{}}` instead. That seems more apt than redefining the `\finentrypunct`, plus it will check if there is any comment and if that is not the case, no line break will be inserted.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently you cannot add multiple `\DeclareSourcemap` to a latex file since only the last one it taken into account.

---

One Solution can be to declare only one source map and modify the entries manually

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey,match=\regexp{^a$},final]
      \step[fieldset=note,fieldvalue={one note}]
    }
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=entrykey,match=\regexp{^b$},final]
      \step[fieldset=note,fieldvalue={another note}]
    }
  }
}
```