# biblatex custom reference

Tags: biblatex

I've been searching for a way to create "Custom References" with biblatex, but haven't found a solution to my problem. Among "normal sources" like Journal Articles, I need other references where I can put a custom sentence in it. Like "[3] This was performed by someone else".

Is there an option to do that?

```
 \documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}

@article{entry1, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\cite{entry1}
So far so good, now I need another reference that says 'This was performed by someone else'.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more what exactly you need? If all you want is to put some custom text next to where you `\cite` stuff, but leave the appearance of the bibliography as is, try `\cite[<pre text>][<post text>]{<bibID>}`.

Comment: Wouldn't `\cite{dude} This was performed by someone else` give *"[3] This was performed by someone else"*?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something similar to footnotes or endnotes!?

Comment: Yes, for footnotes you can just add \footnote{blah}. However, when i cite, I need something with the corrresponding label in the .bib-file.
What I need:
...has been reported by Will.[1] However, the other thing is new.[2]

Now in the bibliography:
[1] Will, Journal, Year, Pages.
[2] Here I need my custom text. And only this text.

Comment: Mhhh, all I could find is [biblatex + \mcite; add arbitrary text in references with subentries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/171175/35864) maybe that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`notes2bib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) seems to be what you are after, it provides a `\bibnote` command that places a note in the bibliography.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber,sorting=none]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
We cite something \cite{aksin} and now a note \bibnote{just a note}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a matter of fact `biblatex`'s `notes2bib` support seems to do something similar to what greyshade did in their answer.

Comment: Thanks! Will see which option is more convenient. Probably notes2bib, since this does not require an entry in the .bib-file. :)

Comment: @screeny2 I would think so, `notes2bib` creates the entry in the `.bib` file automatically and on-the-fly.

Comment: alright, didn't know that!

Answer (score 2):

What you want seems to be blatant abuse and not really fitting into what a bibliography is supposed to be - but it's easy to achieve:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,style=chem-angew]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{entry1, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}
@misc{thething,
    title = "This is some custom text about something else"
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter One}
Something has been reported by \textcite{entry1}, while something else is new \cite{thething}.
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But you have to do what your boss wants sometimes...;-)

Thanks a lot!