# How to generate a new reference identifier by citing the same bib entry, with a twist

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I am preparing an article for a journal that currently does not have a LaTeX template, but all of my material is in LaTeX. It has a somewhat special reference citation guide I have not seen yet, so maybe my question has an easy answer and there is already a package available since I am not an expert on all styles, so I did not know what to search for. If that does not exist, I'd like to create one either in `bibtex` or `biblatex`.

*The rule is* that each `\cite{}` generates a new entry `[x]` in the text and in the References section. If a citation key was already referenced in the past, then it simply refers to the first citation with a comment. For the MWE below, this should result in the References list to be rendered as (with proper inline numbering of course, where `[1, Lemelisk et. al, Chapter 3, p. 123]` should be replaced with `[2]`):

**References**

[1] B. Lemelisk, W. Tarkin, D. Vader, and D. Sidious. Death Star. Alderaan and Yavin 4, 0 BBY.

[2] Lemelisk et al., Chapter 3, p. 123 [1]

[3] B. Lemelisk, W. Tarkin, D. Vader, and D. Sidious. Death Star II. Endor, 4 ABY.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc
{
  death-star,
  author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
  title        = {{Death Star}},
  howpublished = {Alderaan and Yavin 4},
  year         = {0 BBY}
}
@misc
{
  death-star-2,
  author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
  title        = {{Death Star II}},
  howpublished = {Endor},
  year         = {4 ABY}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

They first built \emph{Death Star}~\cite{death-star}.

\lipsum[1]

The design flaw was found in \cite[Lemelisk et al., Chapter 3, p. 123]{death-star}.

\lipsum[2]

To address the flaw, they designed \emph{Death Star 2}~\cite{death-star-2}
that featured many smaller diameter heat exhaust vents.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe think of the bibliography as a set of endnotes containing full references and then think of footnotes as converting to endnotes. Just this seems sufficiently similar to some footnote-referencing styles for it to potentially be useful to think about their approach. `biblatex` is generally a lot easier to adapt so, unless you can find a good match in terms of a `.bst` file, you might want to go in the `biblatex` direction, since that's an option. What's the journal?

Comment: The journal is [Leonardo](http://www.leonardo.info/isast/journal/editorial/edguides.html) and they are expressly against footnotes though. However, they do treat them as endnotes indeed. What would be the styles you refer to? While I am more familiar with bibtex, biblatex is certainly an option if it's easier to do what I need in it.

Comment: @cfr Hinted by your comment I came across [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56145/is-there-a-way-to-move-all-footnotes-to-the-end-of-the-document). Now I see better what you are saying is to somehow "merge" `endnotes` and bibliography, by treating the the latter as special type of endnotes... I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: This could indeed be done with `biblatex`'s `xref`, a separate entry for the second citation `\cite[Lemelisk et al., Chapter 3, p. 123]{death-star}` and some modification (quite some modification actually, I think) to the cite macros.

Comment: Another possible way might be to use the [`notes2bib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/notes2bib) package (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199061/35864), for example).

Comment: @moewe I'll check out `xref` and `notes2bib`. The latter seems a bit more manual, but definitively a plausible workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I would definitely prefer a solution using `xref`. A `notes2bib` solution is a bit more manual, but not *much* more than your example above, I would have thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a complete solution but I hope that it will give you the basis of one. To tweak the formatting (e.g., if you want just first initials or whatever), see the `biblatex` manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-note, notetype=endonly, singletitle=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}    
% I haven't tested with BibTeX, so I don't want this code uncommented here. However, I gather from an edit that Serguei has determined it to work with the BibTeX backend. To use this, comment the previous line and uncomment the next. Note, however, that some features are not supported by the legacy backend.  
% \usepackage[citestyle=verbose-note, notetype=endonly, singletitle=false, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc
    {
        death-star,
        author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
        title        = {{Death Star}},
        howpublished = {Alderaan and Yavin 4},
        year         = {0 BBY}
    }
    @misc
    {
        death-star-2,
        author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
        title        = {{Death Star II}},
        howpublished = {Endor},
        year         = {4 ABY}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\def\enotesize{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\notesname}{References}
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\mkbibbrackets{\theenmark}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{% adapted from verbose-note.cbx
    \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}{}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \printtext{%
        \mkbibbrackets{%
            \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}%
        \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
        {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
            {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
            {}
            {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
                \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
        {}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    They first built \emph{Death Star}~\autocite{death-star}.

    \lipsum[1]

    The design flaw was found in \autocite[Lemelisk et al., Chapter 3, p. 123][]{death-star}.

    \lipsum[2]

    To address the flaw, they designed \emph{Death Star 2}~\autocite{death-star-2}
    that featured many smaller diameter heat exhaust vents.

    \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\mkbibbrackets{\theenmark}\addspace}
    \theendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: tweaked references as endnotes]

**EDIT** [by Serguei]

- A [GitHub style project](https://github.com/smokhov/latex-styles) for `leonardo.cls` was started and used in a couple of article submissions based on this answer. Further contributions are welcome.

Comment: I've edited and accepted the answer the way it works for me. [I've started `leonardo.cs` on GitHub](https://github.com/smokhov/latex-styles) based on the above answer as I used it in a couple of submissions, so any future updated can be carried over there. I've put the credits I could glean from here :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the crossref field of bibtex is what you are looking for.
with crossref, the bibitem copies fields it's missing from the parent (which thus makes a very bad job with the misc here...), adds the fields added in the reference (the 'comment'), and reference it in the biblio.

With your example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @misc{death-star-a,
      author       = {Bevel Lemelisk and Wilhuff Tarkin and Darth Vader and Darth Sidious},
      title        = {{Death Star}},
      howpublished = {Alderaan and Yavin 4},
      year         = {0 BBY}
    }
    @misc{death-star-b,
      crossref     = {death-star-a},
      chapter      = {3},
      pages        = {123}
    }
    @misc{death-star-2,
      title        = {{Death Star II}},
      howpublished = {Endor},
      year         = {4 ABY}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

They first built \emph{Death Star}~\cite{death-star-a}.

\lipsum[1]

The design flaw was found in \cite{death-star-b}.

\lipsum[2]

To address the flaw, they designed \emph{Death Star 2}~\cite{death-star-2}
that featured many smaller diameter heat exhaust vents.

\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) this solution does not scale for many citations unfortunately additionally forcing the addition of rarely used bib-entries in the bib file, and (2) the issue with crossref is that it would only generate one entry in References and in the body not necessarily sequentially. For example, if I `\cite[Foo]{death-star}`, `\cite[Bar]{death-star}`, and `\cite[Baz]{death-star}` in the body after the last cite in MWE, I'd expect `[4] Foo [1]`, `[5] Bar [1]`, `[6] Baz [1]`, crossref might mess up with this if I switch to something more actual than `abbrv`. Though the main problem is the scale here.

Comment: (2) is solved with @PREAMBLE{"\newcommand{\noopsort}[1]{}"} as explained in [Bibtex doc](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) p4-5.

(1) It is not very scalable indeed, but at least it's both correct and not that complex, particularly as the style require some comment, specifying the content 'location' within the whole reference (I'm guessing).